# Where can I print a document in Vancouver?

Tags: vancouver, services

I'm traveling in Canada and currently I'm in Vancouver. I need to print a PDF file (5 times 4 pages) that is on my Laptop / USB stick. What options do I have in (downtown) Vancouver? What is the price I have to pay for that?

Comment: If you're staying in a hotel, they're very likely to do it for you, either at reception or the business centre. Prices vary between hotels though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPS Store Canada will do the same. It has [print online](https://theupsstorecanada.webprint.com/home_en.php) service: you upload your stuff and pick it up at the nearest UPS Store (just downtown there are four). As for cost, check the [printing price estimation](https://theupsstorecanada.webprint.com/webprint/documents/price_quote.jspa).

Answer (score 4):

[FedEx Office](http://www.fedex.com/us/office/) is a chain of copy shops with 1900 locations in the US and Canada.  The locator tool on their website doesn't seem to be working for me at the moment, but Google shows a location in Vancouver at Broadway and Cypress, and there appears to be another one somewhere near the convention center (Google shows a number of locations near there, some of which are probably wrong).  They have self-service printers from which you can print a PDF from a USB drive (or via email or other means).  The cost may vary but should be under 10 cents per page or so.  I believe most of their stores are open 24 hours.

Note that until a couple of years ago, the best-known chain in the retail print/copy business (at least in the US) was Kinko's, but FedEx bought the company and rebranded the stores.  So if you're asking locals for directions and they've never heard of FedEx Office, try asking them where the Kinko's is.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in the same situation, I found [Vancouver Business Plus](http://www.yelp.ca/biz/vancouver-business-plus-vancouver) on Robson Street would print, scan and more.  It's pretty centrally located.

There are also several internet cafes, if you do a simple google search for it.  Prices vary a little and you generally pay per minute/hour for the internet usage, and then a few cents per page to print.